# Better or the same: CPU memcpy() vs device cudaMemcpy() on pinned, mapped memory in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, memcpy

I have:

- Host memory that has been successfully pinned and mapped using `cudaHostAlloc(..., cudaHostAllocMapped)` or `cudaHostRegister(..., cudaHostRegisterMapped)`;
- Device pointers have been obtained using `cudaHostGetDevicePointer(...)`.

I initiate `cudaMemcpy(..., cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice)` on src and dest device pointers that point to two different regions of pinned+mapped memory obtained by the technique above.
Everything works fine.

*Question: should I continue doing this or just use a traditional CPU-style `memcpy()` since everything is in system memory anyway? ...or are they the **same** (i.e. does `cudaMemcpy` map to a straight `memcpy` when both src and dest are pinned)?*

(I am still using the `cudaMemcpy` method because previously everything was in device global memory, but have since switched to pinned memory due to gmem size constraints)

Comment: It's an interesting question. Provided you use an optimized memcpy, the CPU is probably better - the memory belongs to it, after all - and a discrete GPU's ability to do host->host memcpy is limited to PCIe bandwidth.  But if the GPU would be idle otherwise, why not?

Comment: I hope the GPU wouldn't be doing the copy.  I hope the runtime would see that the pointers are both host pointers and invoke a host memcpy. I have asked to find out what actually happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `cudaMemcpy` the CUDA driver detects that you are copying from a host pointer to a host pointer and the copy is done on the CPU. You can of course use memcpy on the CPU yourself if you prefer.

If you use `cudaMemcpy`, there may be an extra stream synchronize performed before doing the copy (which you may see in the profiler, but I'm guessing there—test and see).

On a UVA system you can just use `cudaMemcpyDefault` as talonmies says in his answer. But if you don’t have UVA (sm_20+ and 64-bit OS), then you have to call the right copy (e.g. `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice`). If you `cudaHostRegister()` everything you are interested in then `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice` will end up doing the following depending on the where the memory is located:

- Host <-> Host: performed by the CPU (memcpy)
- Host <-> Device: DMA (device copy engine)
- Device <-> Device: Memcpy CUDA kernel (runs on the SMs, launched by driver)

Comment: very interestig, do you have some source where you found the infos?

Comment: I believe I asked my NVIDIA colleagues for implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on a platform with UVA (unified virtual addressing), I would strongly suggest using `cudaMemcpy` with `cudaMemcpyDefault`. That way all of this handwringing about the fastest path becomes an internal API implementation detail you don't have to worry about.

Comment: Yes and no, I often work on a C1060, but have access to C2050/70's. So what about in regards to my pinned memory question specifically--do you know what `cudaMemcpyDefault` does behind the scenes in this case? That would answer the question pretty much.

Comment: I don't work.for NVIDIA so I haven't seen any code, but it appears look at the source and destination pointers and at accordingly. You will get a host side copy with a host pointer and a device to device copy with a device pointer